# Are there any running commentaries on grace after meals?

Tags: commentaries, bentching, rishonim

I would like to know if there are any authors from the period of the rishonim or earlier who have compiled a running commentary on birkat hamazon.

Comment: Just about every author of a peirush on the siddur included a commentary on birkas hamazon. This includes the Ri Ben Yakar, Abudarham, and Machzor Vitri

Comment: Also the Shibbolei Haleket 157 and Kol-Bo 25 discuss several of the phrases in birkas hamazon, commenting on them

Answer (score 2):

The [Abudarham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abudirham) has a running commentary [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham,_Laws_of_Blessings,_First_Gate;_Blessing_on_Bread.46) (in Sefaria, it starts at paragraph 46ff).

[Rabbi Zedekiah ben Rabbi Avraham HaRofe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zedekiah_ben_Abraham_Anaw) wrote a short commentary in *Shibbolei HaLeqeṭ* 157.

Seder [Rav Amram Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amram_Gaon) ([starting at page 350 =175b of the printed page numbers](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Rav_Amrom_Gaon_1.pdf)) has a running commentary.

[Rabbi Eleazar of Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) has a commentary in *siman* 147 of his commentary on the Siddur (פירושי סידור התפילה לרוקח).

You can also look at the [Tur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arba%27ah_Turim) on *Orach Ḥayyim* *simanim* [187](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x847)-189.

---

(h/t to @Matt for some of these)